# Escaping newlines in the presence of literal "\" + "n"

Tags: c#, escaping, newline

In my app's settings file, each line takes the form *name=value* (example: *color=red*). The names are determined by the app, whereas the values are text typed by the user.

Since the file format requires one setting per line, there's a problem if the user's value contains a line break ("\n", ASCII 10): this will crash the parser (or allow them to insert fake *name=value* records with invalid names). However, I do want the user to be able to use this character, so I need to escape it somehow: for example, `s = s.Replace("\n", "\\n");`

However, the user might also type the two-character sequence "\" + "n". So suppose I have any arbitrary nasty string like **"ABC\n\\n\\\\n\n\\\nXYZ"** (which has two line breaks and two literal "\" + "n" sequences in it). What algorithm will safely (i) escape the string, to ensure it contains no newlines, and then (ii) reverse the process to recover the original string?

Comment: Have you considered not writting your own parser for this job and rather use an "established" parser and file format like json or XML?

Comment: To parse that you'd need to go through each character and when you see a `\\` you  set a flag that the next character is escaped and then handle that next character accordingly and unset the flag.  But it's much better to find a parser to handle that for you instead.

Comment: If you actually tried to implement this encoding/decoding you would find that it's not hard to do.

Comment: It sounds as if the parser in question was not designed to handle the grammar you have designed. Instead of trying to circumvent this abuse of the parser's specification, why not instead modify the parser directly? Or use a different parser (+1 for Rand Random)? (A _crashing_ parser on malformed user defined input sounds suspicious.)

Comment: I'd just javascript/json encode string values. Using JSON.NET, a round-trip looks like this: `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject("hello\n\n"))`

Comment: JSON may be a future option. XML can be a pain because of versioning issues (schema elements added/removed over time). Re "500"'s comment, I did try, but got stuck, hence posting here; perhaps I'm just not as clever as you. Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you only want to handle `'\n'`, the following methods will work:

```
string Parse(string input)
{
    return input.Replace("\\","\\\\").Replace("\n","\\n");
}

string ParseBack(string input)
{
    string output="";
    for(int i=0; i < input.Length; i++)
    {
        if(input[i]=='\\')
        {
            i++;
            if(input[i]=='n')
            {
                output += '\n';
            }
            else 
            {
                output += input[i];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            output += input[i];
        }
    }
    return output;
}
```

Input:

```
ABC 
\n\\n 
\ 
XYZ
```

Parsed:

```
ABC\n\\n\\\\n\n\\\nXYZ
```

ParsedBack:

```
ABC 
\n\\n 
\ 
XYZ
```

Comment: `ParseBack` swallows stand-alone backslash.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError stand-alone backslash will be parsed as a double backslash which will be parsed back as a stand-alone backslash.

Answer (score -1):

First of, you can use the `@"string"`, which will stop the escape sequence

So basically, `@"\n"` will turn out as `\n` and not as newline

To your line break inside the value of a user, I had this Problem too and I managed it by replacing the newline-char (`\n`) with something a user would never type (for example `<|NewLine|>`). When I write or read from the file I replace the corresponding values

To replace the newline-char with something else isn't the best solution, but I like to use it because it's rather simple to me

Comment: The OP's string are probably not coming out of compile-time literals.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError 100% not compile-time literals since OP said `The names are determined by the app, whereas the values are text typed by the user.`